# Time Limit Exceeded Leetcode: How can I optimize my code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, sub-array

I am trying to solve the `Two Sum II - Input Array Is Sorted` question on leetcode, it's giving me `Time Limit Exceeded` so I guess my code isn't optimized well and needs more efficient solutions. But I am not so good at it so to be specific how can I remove two `for-loops` with one in my code.

Ques1: `Two Sum II - Input Array Is Sorted`

> Given a 1-indexed array of integers numbers that is already sorted in non-decreasing order, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number. Let these two numbers be numbers[index1] and numbers[index2] where 1 <= index1 < index2 <= numbers.length.

> Return the indices of the two numbers, index1 and index2, added by one as an integer array [index1, index2] of length 2.
> The tests are generated such that there is exactly one solution. You may not use the same element twice.
> Your solution must use only constant extra space.

Example:

```
Input: numbers = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [1,2]
Explanation: The sum of 2 and 7 is 9. Therefore, index1 = 1, index2 = 2. We return [1, 2].
```

Ques [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-ii-input-array-is-sorted/)

My code: Test cases `20 / 21`

```
var twoSum = function(numbers, target) {
      let arr=[];
    for(let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    let findNum= target - numbers[i];
        for(let j=i+1;j<numbers.length; j++){
           if(numbers[j]===findNum)
               arr.push(i+1, j+1);
        }
    }
    return arr
};
```

How can I optimize my code so that it can run all test cases?

Comment: First, if the `numbers` array is non-decreasing, you don't need to go until the end of the array in neither loop, because if `numbers[i] + numbers[j] > target` there is no way, you can still fulfill your condition. Second: once you found a match, you can directly return the result and don't need to continue the loops ... But that would still be O(n^2). A O(n) approach would start from both sides of the array and step towards the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer for Question 2. You have nested for loops. The nested loop will run for n - i times each time, where i varies from 1 to n. So the total time complexity of the code would be (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 0, which would be (n*(n-1))/2. This is order O(n^2) solution. In the question n is 3 * 10^4 which would result in more than 10^8 operations a second. So it will give Time Limit Exceeded error. Now to solve this, you can use the property of sorted array. We can take two pointers, one at the beginning of the array and one at the last index. There would be three cases:

1. If the sum of both the indices is greater than the required target, we will decrement the last pointer index by 1.
2. If the sum of the indices is smaller, then we will increment the first pointer by 1.
3. If the sum is equal to target, we will return the indices.

We will do it till i is not equal to j. Here is the full code.

```
    var twoSum = function(numbers, target) {
    enter code here
        let ans = [];
        while(i<j) {
            if(numbers[i] + numbers[j] > target) {
                j--;
            }
            else if(numbers[i] + numbers[j] < target) {
                i++;
            }
            else {
                ans.push(i+1);
                ans.push(j+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two-pointer approach,

- Start with left = 0 and right = length -1
- Iterate while left < right until you find numbers[left] + numbers[right] === target

I will not post the actual answer because that would spoil the fun.